# Where do I report an issue in X windows/QT that is probably related to Arm64?

Tags: server, kubuntu, xorg, arm

On my old VM, I have Kubuntu 23.04 installed and everything works well.

As part of my hardware migration to Apple Silicon, I am now running Arm64 Ubuntu 23.04 in a VM.  I had to install the Kubuntu packages using "apt-get install kubuntu-desktop" as there is no official arm distribution of Kubuntu.

My X server is a headless X server running TigerVNC.

I have found that moving around windows on the Arm64 system, the window can get into a state where I can no longer reliably click on it.  So far, I have just closed the applications and reopened them to fix this issue.  I would like to report it so at least it is known even if what I am using is not officially supported, but I am not sure what project I should go to.  Are there any litmus tests I can apply to determine this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: For fastest response, the *development* release is the place to test for issues, and if it occurs with the latest KDE Plasma, and is a KDE Plasma issue only, then reporting upstream to the KDE Bug Tracker (https://bugs.kde.org/).  All Ubuntu projects use launchpad, thus `ubuntu-bug` is usually the place to start... some teams do prefer GitHub, so you can also place there, but bug triagers will help you if you ask or make it clear you're willing to help. You are correct no Kubuntu Desktop ISOs exist for *arm64*; only the Ubuntu Desktop  (*if you're willing to help QA the latest daily*)

Comment: My aim with this question was to find someone who might point me in the right direction as to which package might be at fault.  I might even try debugging it myself if I had time on this upcoming holiday weekend.  With no answers forthcoming, I went ahead and picked plasma shell as the possible culprit and reported the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-workspace/+bug/2033449). Maybe close the question?